# Cannot 'save all' in .NET database project in VS 2017 (Cannot access a disposed object)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Usually I can just press 'save all' in my Visual Studio project. But for whatever reason, suddenly I cannot.

When I press 'save all' I get a 'Save File As' dialogue box asking where I would like to save my .sqlproj file. This is unusual, since it usually just overwrites the existing .sqlproj file.

when I select the existing file I can an error that says:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DirectoryWatcher'

I just installed he Fall Creators Update. Could this be related?

Comment: If you are saving to a OneDrive directory & have Files-On-Demand active then that will be the cause: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/100424/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-2.html + lots of other issues/

Comment: Thank you - I thought it might be related to onedrive somehow

Comment: Me too. Thanks. You should probably add your comment as an answer